# ASP.NET Core MVC : controller returning the model parsed on querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

The solution is ASP.NET Core MVC. I have a view with a form, which has 2 submit buttons. These buttons must call 2 different actions in the controller, both on post. I have resolved adding

```
formaction="@Url.Action("action1", @Model)" formmethod="post"
```

on both of the buttons.

This is the action called [PostCall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfCQ9.png) where I receive the model correctly.

But when I return the view passing the updated model, the view is updated with the new data, but i can also see the whole model on the [QueryString](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OuOj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you get the model inside the url as the querystring is you put the model inside the action url `formaction="@Url.Action("action1", @Model)" formmethod="post"` .

As you know post method will put the model inside the request body, so there is no need to put the model inside the Url.Action method.

I suggest you could remove the @Model like this and test again.

`formaction="@Url.Action("action1")" formmethod="post"`

Comment: I have changed the logic of the page. But yes, this is the answer to my problem